# Query returning false though it's true

Tags: php

When `$id` is ***abc@a.b***, it returns **true**. This is as expected!

> But when `$id` is ***1234567***, it returns **false**. This is **not**
>   as expected!

#### My Database:

```
+----+---------+---------+-----------+
| Id |  Email  |  Mobile |  Password |
+----+---------+---------+-----------+
| 15 | abc@a.b | 1234567 |$2y$10$ix..|
+----+---------+---------+-----------+
```

#### My Code:

```
public function customer_login($id,$password)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Email=:_email");
            $stmt->execute(array(":_email"=>$id));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $id = $userRow['Id'];

            $stmtM = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Mobile=:_mobile");
            $stmtM->execute(array(":_mobile"=>$id));
            $userRowM=$stmtM->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $id = $userRowM['Id'];

                    if (password_verify($password, $userRow['Password']) || password_verify($password, $userRowM['Password'])) 
                    {

                        $_SESSION['customer'] = $id;
                        return true;

                        }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

When `$id` is ***abc@a.b***, it returns **true**. This is as expected!

> But when `$id` is ***1234567***, it returns **false**. This is **not**
>   as expected!

Comment: There is no need for two queries. If I understand correctly then you simply want users to log in via email or mobile so MySQL conveniently has the `OR` operator. Just do `$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Email=:_id OR Mobile=:_id"); $stmt->execute(array(":_id"=>$id));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line, you are changing the value of $id. The $id variable gets the value of 'Id' field of your table and that is fed into the mobile number based second query. This is the reason, your mobile number based query does not return any result and returns false.

```
$id = $userRow['Id'];
```

Assign the above to a different variable and keep $id intact as the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Change this: 
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Email=:_email");
        $stmt->execute(array(":_email"=>$id));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $id = $userRow['Id'];

        $stmtM = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE 
       Mobile=:_mobile");
        $stmtM->execute(array(":_mobile"=>$id));
        $userRowM=$stmtM->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $id = $userRowM['Id'];


        //to this : 
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Email=:_email or 
        Mobile=:_mobile limit 0,1 ");
        $stmt->execute(array(":_email"=>$id , ":_mobile"=>$id ));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $id = $userRow['Id'];
```

Comment: Why limit 0,1 ?

Comment: cus i thought your looking for a row that mobile or email equals id, for example if you are checking user creds to login, this is important. you can remove limit if you dont need it

Comment: In that case, you mean to say the mobile and email column should be unique..., right?

Comment: yes. should be unique in two ways. emails and mobiles should be unique and a mobile shouldnt be found in email cols and an email shuouldnt be found in miobile cols